# Llamada al sistema con caracteres especiales

Tags: c

En mi siguiente paso necesito listar mis adaptadores de red de manera que pueda seleccionar uno de ellos y ver sus servidores DNS.

Finalmente he logrado listarlos e implementar correctamente una llamada tipo leecad que almacene mi variable y pueda seleccionar el adaptador en cuestión, mostrando sus servidores DNS. Sin embargo, sucede que eso funciona en nombres del tipo `Ethernet`, pero para `Loopback...` o `Conexión...`, donde figuran guiones o tildes, me devuelve error.

[image: Explicación gráfica de mi problema]

¿Cómo podría solventar ese fallo?

Este es mi código:

```
FILE* f = _popen("netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces", "r");
if (f == NULL) {
    printf("Error.");
    exit(1);
}
printf("Los adaptadores de red disponibles son los siguientes:\n\n");
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, f) != NULL) {
    printf("%s", line);
}
printf("Escriba el nombre del adaptador del que quiere consultar: ");
leecad(adaptador, 100);
_pclose(f);
printf("\n\n");
strcpy(str, "netsh interface ipv4 show dnsservers ");
strcat(str, adaptador);
system(str);
```

Adjunto mi método `leecad`:

```
int leecad(char* cad, int n) {
    int i, c;
    c = getchar();
    if (c == EOF) {
        cad[0] = '\0';
        return 0;
    }
    if (c == '\n')
        i = 0;
    else {
        cad[0] = c;
        i = 1;
    }
    for (; i < n - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
        cad[i] = c;
    cad[i] = '\0';
    if (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    return 1;
};
```

Comment: ¿Cómo está guardada la información en el archivo? ¿Qué tipo de formato usas? Existen muchas formas de leer los datos del archivo, pero eso dependerá del formato que use.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres exactamente? Esta vez no hay archivo de redirección. La información que quiero leer de _popen es directamente la que imprimiría la consola mediante el comando de netsh en cmd, no sé si es eso. Con lo que sea, me haces saber. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Por qué llamas a `_popen` en vez de a `popen`?

Comment: Para compilar correctamente vía Windows. Sin embargo, he conseguido mi acometido y he replanteando mi problema, reduciéndolo simplemente al de caracteres raros.

Comment: El problema parece estar en `leecad( )`, que, cosas de la vida, **no muestras**. Y digo `parece estar` porque tu pregunta no está clara. Indicas que hay un fallo: **¿Cual es exactamente el *fallo*?** Creo que deberías consultar lo que es un [mcve].

Comment: Edito con mi bloque leecad adjunto, pero dudo que sea el motivo de mi error ya que precisamente es el que ha cedido mi tutor (y espero que su dominio de C sea competente). Aparte de eso, no sé en qué otra exposición puedo ayudar. El error es el que he añadido antes como captura, es decir, si no hago uso de caracteres tipo guión, tildes... cumple con su acometido, que es el de mostrar servidores DNS.

Comment: Cuando decis que hay un error, tenes que describir que es un error. El programa no hace lo que se espera? se cuelga? tira un error en tiempo de ejecucion? no termina?

Comment: He releído mi exposición y ya explicaba a qué me refiero, no sólo con la captura. No se hace lo esperado, que es llamar correctamente al sistema y mostrar los servidores DNS, como sí sucede al insertar adaptadores que no tienen caracteres "raros" en su nombre.

Comment: Estas encarando mal tu pregunta... vos estas generando una llamada a una funcion del SO y eso es lo que tira error. Sin embargo, tu pregunta no muestra como generas la cadena de esa llamada, ni como es la cadena, ni nada de todo eso que es lo que hace que tengas un error. Fijate que lo que van a necesitar para ayudarte, es justamente eso...

Comment: Perdón. Añadí más parte del código. No soy receloso con ello pero a veces pienso que menos es más (para evitar lectura de más innecesaria) y claramente me he pasado recortando. Para cualquier otro detalle, ya me diréis.

Comment: y de alguna forma, podes mostrar lo que viene en la cadena adaptador? porque el SO esta protestando que eso es lo que esta mal... y eso es lo que hay que ver que contiene...

Comment: "Adaptador" es una variable tipo char que hace referencia a la interfaz de red seleccionada. Mediante leecad escribo el nombre de mi adaptador, como un scanf que admite espacios, y si éste no contiene ningún caracter especial me lanza el comando necesario para ofrecerme la información sobre los servidores DNS ("netsh interface ipv4 show dnsservers " + el texto recogido por la variable). El fallo viene dado cuando el texto recogido contiene tildes, guiones y demás.

Comment: Por eso... proba ejecutar ese comando a mano.. probablemente como tenga caracteres especiales haya que hacer algo especial...